# How can I implement a toggle for a drawer using a menu button within a BottomNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

//Bottom Navigator

```
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Menu"
        component={DrawerNavigator}
        listeners={({navigation}) => ({
          tabPress: e => {
            e.preventDefault(); // Prevents the default behavior
            navigation.toggleDrawer(); // Open the drawer
          },
        })}
        options={{
          tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => {
            return (
              <View style={styles.tabBarItem}>
                <Image
                  source={require('../assets/icons/menu1.png')}
                  resizeMode="contain"
                  style={[
                    styles.icon,
                    focused ? styles.iconFocused : styles.iconInactive,
                  ]}
                />
                <Text
                  style={[
                    styles.label,
                    focused ? styles.labelFocused : styles.labelInactive,
                    {fontWeight: 'bold'},
                  ]}>
                  Menu
                </Text>
              </View>
            );
          },
        }}
      />
```

//DrawerNavigator

```
<Drawer.Navigator
  screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
  initialRouteName="DrawerScreens"
>
  <Drawer.Screen
    name="DrawerScreens"
    component={DrawerScreens}
    options={{
      drawerLabel: "Home",
      drawerIcon: () => {
        return (
          <Image
            source={require("../assets/icons/home1.png")}
            resizeMode="contain"
            style={styles.icon}
          />
        );
      },
    }}
  />
</Drawer.Navigator>;
```

How can I implement a toggle for a drawer using a menu button within a BottomNavigator? When the drawer is open, I'd like to enable navigation to different tabs by clicking on them, while ensuring the BottomNavigator remains visible.

I have tried, but i keep getting this error

ERROR  The action 'REPLACE' with payload {"name":"DrawerNavigator"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'DrawerNavigator'?

Answer (score 0):

Make `Drawer` the parent of `Tab` navigator, which allows `Tab` to access `Drawer`'s methods. Something like this:

```js
function Tabs() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
...
      <Tab.Screen
        name="Menu"
...
        listeners={({ navigation }) => ({
          tabPress: (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            navigation.toggleDrawer();
          },
        })}
      />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

<Drawer.Navigator>
  <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Tabs} />
...
</Drawer.Navigator>
```

Comment: i tried it but Tab.Screen requires a component

Comment: Just give a component, it can be an "empty" one: component={<View/>}.